# FOSUserBundle and custom fields in user entity

Tags: symfony, field, message, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle with custom fields in my user class.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(min="3", max="255", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     */
     protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Message", mappedBy="fromUser")
     */
    protected $sentMessages;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Message", mappedBy="toUser")
     */
    protected $receivedMessages;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    protected $dateRegistered;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=250, nullable=true)
     * 
     */
    protected $banReason;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->dateRegistered = new \DateTime();
    }
    /*  getters and setters */

}
```

I want to show a personal message to the locked users, filling **$banReason** field.
I found that **error.user** variable contains part of the user entity, but my field is set to null instead of it's real value.

[image: screenshot of error.user variable output]

Sorry, but i'm kinda noob in hooks and services. :-(

Have a nice day!

Comment: Where is the error.user variable you're talking about? I cannot see it anywhere in the code.

Comment: It's in the login form of the bundle.